# how many email have been sent using mail function php

Tags: php, email, while-loop

Is there any way possible to find out the total number of sent emails from php mail function. My mail function is inside a while loop and I want to know the number of sent emails.

Thanks

Comment: count it.. `if (mail(...)) $sent++;`

Comment: Unless you are asking for a way to know how many have been sent before introducing such a counter.  In that case, the logs should tell you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to know the number of mails accepted for delivery in the while loop, add a counter variable:

```
$mailsSent = 0;
while($condition) {
    if (mail('foo@example.com', 'My Subject', 'My Message')) {
        $mailsSent++;
    }
}
echo $mailsSent;
```

For the total amount of mails accepted for delivery, you can configure a log file in php.ini

> **`mail.log`** string
>
> The path to a log file that will log all `mail()` calls. Log entries include the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log

If you want to know the number of mails which actually got sent, check the sendmail log.

Answer (score 1):

**Re-Edited the Answer! Please check now. I was confused at first!**

You can use this way to check how many mails have been sent by using this script:

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    while ($condition) {
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
            $count++;
    }
    echo "Totally, $count messages have been sent!";
?>
```

Comment: Also you haven't initialized `$count`.

Comment: @PeeHaa I just mentioned the part code. Will update with the full code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the solution for my problem!

Comment: @user1349390 Great! What happened? What was the issue?

Comment: I've removoed my dv. But please don't add "taglines" to your posts. "Hope it helps".

Comment: @PraveenKumar there was not issue. I just did not think of using $count++; to my codes :)
PeeHaa Sure it helps. Thanks